# Bit manipulation (shifting)

Tags: c, bit

There is a piece of code I'm looking at that does:

```
int result = 0 ;
char byte = foo[j]
for (i = 7 ; i>0 ; i--) {
   byte = (byte & ~0x1)>>1 ;
   result+= array[i] * (byte & 1) ;
}
```

I know that the objective of this code is to multiply the elements of the array for which the corresponding bits in byte are set to 1.

I don't understand why the ~0x1 is necessary though, as every time, I'm only considering the last bit

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could just use an unsigned char and skip that bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain compilers implement >> by rotating bits instead of shifting them. This guards against this case (if the last bit is set to 0, then even if the shifting is implemented as a rotation, the answer will remain correct)

Comment: Explaining this a bit more: right-shifts of positive (or zero) values have to bring in zero bits on the left. But right-shifting a negative value, it's implementation-defined what happens. So in theory a compiler could use a rotate instruction if and only if it knew that `byte` had a negative value.  Also, relying on this behaviour is a terrible idea because other compilers (or other versions of the same compiler) might do it differently.

Comment: The C standard does not allow replacing the shift with a rotation tout court, the only corner cases are shifting a negative integer (where the result is implementation-defined), shifting of a negative quantity (undefined behavior) and shifting of more than the size of the operand (undefined behavior).

Answer (score -2):

`(byte & ~0x1)>>1` and `byte>>1` both shift the byte 1 bit right side.
The difference is that `(byte & ~0x1)>>1` only take care of the lowest 8 bits of byte, and `byte>>1` doesn't care any more.
When byte is really a **BYTE**, they are the same.
Or the byte is just a name of type int(long int), they are very different.
`(byte & 0xFF) >> 1` has the same function as `(byte & ~0x1) >>1`.

Comment: What makes you think "`(byte & ~0x1)>>1` only take care of the lowest 8 bits of byte"?

Comment: @RSahu You are right. I assumed the '~0x1' constant is of type byte. After looking at the C standards, I found the '~0x1' constant has a default type of int.